# Ошибка : Object of class WP_Query could not be converted to string

Tags: php, wordpress

пытаюсь в шорткод передать значение от query , но вылетает такая ошибка Object of class WP_Query could not be converted to string

```
 $query = new WP_Query(array('cat' => $category->term_id,'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),));

        echo do_shortcode('[drag_drop_schortcode  query="'.$query.'"]');
```

Как её можно было бы исправить?

Comment: $query - экземпляр класса WP_Query, шорткод ожидает строку. В сообщении об ошибке всё написано. Достаньте из $query необходимое поле и подставьте в функцию шорткода.

Comment: понятно , тогда придется передавать больше чем один параметр